# Angularjs 1.2.6: watch directive's parent scope collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building custom tree directive:

```
<ul tree="treeOptions">
    <li>{{ item.code + ' - ' + item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

In javascript:

```
$scope.myItems = [];
$scope.treeOptions = {
    data: 'myItems',
    ...
}
```

In directive:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('tree', []).
        directive('tree', ['$compile', '$document', function ($compile, 
                                                                $document) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: { treeOptions: '=tree' }, //Isolated scope
                compile: function (elem, attrs) {

                    //...

                    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                        //...

                        scope.$parent.$watchCollection(scope.treeOptions.data, 
                            function (newItems, oldItems) {
                                var addedItems = _.difference(newItems, oldItems);
                                var removedItems = _.difference(oldItems, newItems);
                                //but newItems and oldItems always the same

                                //...
                            }
                        );      
                    }           
                };
            }
        };
    } ]);
})(angular);
```

I'm using lodash ( _ ) to find differences between new and old items.
The problem is newItems and oldItems are always the same, even after new items are pushed to parent scope's myItems array. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried looping through yourself and seeing what is actually contained in each variable?

Comment: Yes, after push, newItems and oldItems both contain pushed items.

Comment: Maybe the function is called numerous times?

Comment: See [issue 2621](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gruff Bunny pointed out in the comments, this is an open issue with AngularJS up to the current version (1.2.13). The workaround for now is to use `$watch( , true)` or do as drew_w suggested.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is definitely an issue in the angular framework. I'm sure they will get around to fixing it sooner or later, but in the mean time if you need to get your code to work I was able to put together a sample that works quite well. The core is to not use the default old/new elements:

```
  var oldWorkingItems = scope.$parent[attrs.testDirective].slice(0);
  scope.$parent.$watchCollection(attrs.testDirective, 
      function (newItems, oldItems) {
        console.log('NEW Items:' + newItems);
        console.log('Old Items:' + oldWorkingItems);
```

For the full example as well as my reproduction of the error, see the following Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/R9hQpRZqrAQoCPdQu3ea?p=preview. By the way, the reason this is called so many times is because it is inside an ng-repeat, but that was my way to force the use of "$parent". Anyways, hope this helps some!

**Edit** - It really annoyed me how many times the directive was being run in the ng-repeat so I wrote another plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/R9hQpRZqrAQoCPdQu3ea?p=preview) that uses a single ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in [1]">
  <div test-directive="testCollection"></div>
</div>
```

This only calls the directive twice (why twice, I'm still not sure).